# Java iterate once while still getting all the values

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, bukkit

I am currently using the Bukkit 1.8 API, and using Java 7.

I have an iteration going on:

```
for(String ranks : plugin.getConfig().getStringList("selllallranks"))
```

Inside of this for-loop I have an if/else statement, seeing if player has a permission. If they do it should send them a message ONCE. However, it is sending it to them 26 times. This is because what it is iterating through has 26 strings inside of it.

I have *tried* searching on [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHMO_enUS582US582&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20iterate%20once%20through%20multiple%20values&es_th=1) for a way to iterate through multiple values one time, while still getting the values, but nothing came up that I liked. How would I iterate through all the values, while still getting all the values inside, sending the code inside *once.*

The reason I can't just add `break;` at the end is because they could have no permission on one of the 26 strings, however one of the 26 strings, they also could have permission. If I did break it would send an invalid message message and continue on with the code if they have permission for other strings.

I am using this to check the permission:

```
if(p.hasPermission("duocraft.sellall." + ranks)){
    // continuing code
}else{
    // send no permission message.
}
```

Comment: Asking two unrelated questions in the same post is not a good idea.

Comment: @AmirAfghani I see how it is not a good idea, I'll just post the second question later, on a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a flag and issue the message after the loop.

Like this:

```
boolean hasPermission = true;
for(String ranks : plugin.getConfig().getStringList("selllallranks")) {
    if(p.hasPermission("duocraft.sellall." + ranks)) {
        // continuing code
    } else {
        hasPermission = false;
    }
}
if(!hasPermission) {
    // send no permission message.
}
```

If you want to keep track of which permissions were missing you can store them in a `Set`:

```
Set<Sting> unPermitted = new HashSet<>();
for(String ranks : plugin.getConfig().getStringList("selllallranks")) {
    if(p.hasPermission("duocraft.sellall." + ranks)) {
        // continuing code
    } else {
        unPermitted.add(ranks);
    }
}
if(!unPermitted.isEmpty()) {
    // send no permission message.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Inside of this for-loop I have an if/else statement, seeing if player
>   has a permission. If they do it should send them a message ONCE.
>   However, it is sending it to them 26 times. This is because what it is
>   iterating through has 26 strings inside of it.

Whats wrong with using the `break` keyword to exit the loop once the condition that sends the player a message is satisfied?

Comment: They could have no permission on one of the 26 strings, however one of the 26 strings, they also could have permission. If I did `break` it would send an invalid message message and continue on with the code if they have permission for other strings. Also The bigger question was _How would I iterate through all the values, while still getting all the values inside, sending the code inside once._